# Cannot read property 'BrowserModule' of undefined in angular2 es5

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using **angular2** **es5** and I get this error.

> Cannot read property 'BrowserModule' of undefined.

My server side is php with laravel 5.3

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>CRM TEST WITH ANGULAR 2 ES5</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="angular2app/css/styles.css">
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<!-- IE required polyfill -->
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/Rx.umd.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-polyfills.js">     </script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.0/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>

<!-- 2. Load our 'modules' -->
<script src='angular2app/js/app/app.js'></script>
<script src='angular2app/js/app/app.module.js'></script>
<script src='angular2app/js/main.js'></script>
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
 <body>
<my-app>
   Loading ...
</my-app>
```

My app.module.js is:

```
(function(app) {
app.AppModule =
ng.core.NgModule({
  imports: [
    ng.platformBrowser.BrowserModule,
    ng.forms.FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    app.AppComponent,
    app.LoginFormComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ app.AppComponent ]
})
.Class({
  constructor: function() {}
});
})(window.app || (window.app = {}));
```

Any idea?